# How do I quickly deploy a Laravel app built using Laravel Sail?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I want to quickly deploy a Laravel app built using Laravel Sail (i.e. inside of a docker container) to a Ubuntu cloud server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Ubuntu VPS has already been configured with a running webserver (with PHP and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) installed), has a configuration enabled for the site, and a SSH user with proper permissions, you can run this command:

```bash
rsync -avz --exclude='vendor' --exclude=.env -e "ssh -p 22 -i ~/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /path/to/laravel/sail/install/ remote_user@ip_address:/path/to/remote/laravel/install
```

`rsync` transfers the Laravel files and directories from the local Docker instance to the remote host, `-avz` is for recursion, compression, and verbosity ([more info](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync+-avz)), `--exclude='vendor' --exclude=.env` excludes Laravel packages (you would install them on remote host afterwards with `composer install`) and environment variables (you may choose to omit this for the first transfer).

Note: there are other files and directories you can/should exclude listed in `.gitignore` but the idea is to have this be a quick and dirty deploy command.

`-e "ssh...` specifies SSH as the remote shell, provides the identity file (private key), and disables Strict Host Key Checking (avoids an extra step). [More info](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-p+22+-i+%7E%2Fid_rsa+-o+StrictHostKeyChecking%3Dno).

Then `rsync` connects to the remote host using the remote username and IP, and transfers the Laravel Sail installation to the remote host.

Note: using `rsync`, the trailing slash is important. A trailing slash on a source path means "copy the contents of this directory". Without a trailing slash it means "copy the directory".